# How to set heroku config vars as an object in python

Tags: python, heroku

im trying to learn how to fetch API using python-flask with heroku as the cloud service

in the app, there's a key to communicate with the source server and i set the config variable (config vars) like

`X_App_APIKeys = {key strings}`

how can i use the variable as an object in my code?

i.e : `myapikeys = X_App_APIKeys`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting environment variables in heroku for flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323666/setting-environment-variables-in-heroku-for-flask-app)

Answer (score 0):

Simply `import os`

Then `myapikeys = os.environ['X_App_APIKeys']`

Notice that this only works on the live app deployed on Heroku when the config has been set up. To run your local instance, replace it with your real key instead.